# Convert dtype from object to int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have

```py
df = df['enrolment'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

changing from `str` to `int` but it doesn't work. Instead, it says:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5,424'
```

I want to change from `objec`t to `int`.  How do I solve this?

```py
df=pd.read_csv('C:/data/intake-enrolment-and-graduates-by-course.csv',sep=',')
print(df['enrolment'].dtypes)
```

Comment: Please, provide more data.  Maybe your file.  With more elements, the community can help you faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `invalid literal` error, the conversion from `str` to `int` fails as you have decimal commas in your numbers. These are nice for readability but throw a wrench into the conversion to integer. Deleting the commas does the trick.

In particular, use

```py
df['enrollment'] = df['enrollment'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

Comment: hello, this time im changing from object to float but what should i do if there are 'na' in my file? it says 'could not convert string to float: 'na''

Comment: That's another problem entirely. As Andre Nevares pointed out, without a proper minimum reproducible example, we can hardly help. I'd experiment with `df.fillna(0)` to replace `NaN`s with zeros.

Comment: i tried using dropna() and fillna(0) but the output still contain 'na'

Comment: In that case, you should add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the form of a data table of a dozen rows or so that entails all special cases in the data that can arise in your sample file. We cannot debug in the blind.

Comment: In this case use `pd.to_numeric(df['enrollment'].str.replace(',', ''), errors='coerce', downcast='infer')`